Running Conda Environment in VS Code for Manim
I installed manim on my mac into a conda environment. In VS Code I changed the interpreter to my environment and tried to run it, but came up with this:
/opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/bin/python "/Users/rizkylubis/Documents/Coding Projects/manim_test.py"

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(manim-env) (base) Rizkys-Macbook-Air:Coding Projects rizkylubis$ /opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/bin/python "/Users/rizkylubis/Documents/Coding Projects/manim_test.py"
(manim-env) (base) Rizkys-Macbook-Air:Coding Projects rizkylubis$ 

When trying to visualize it using the manim extension in VS Code I get a message saying that it can't find ffmpeg
Manim Extension XTerm
Serves as a terminal for logging purpose.

Extension Version 0.2.13

MSV /Users/rizkylubis/Documents/Coding Projects>"/opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/bin/manim" "/Users/rizkylubis/Documents/Coding Projects/manim_test.py" SquareToCircle
/opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Manim Community v0.18.1

╭───────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ──────────────────────╮
│ /opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/cli/render/ │
│ commands.py:119 in render                                                    │
│                                                                              │
│   116 │   │   for SceneClass in scene_classes_from_file(file):               │
│   117 │   │   │   try:                                                       │
│   118 │   │   │   │   with tempconfig({}):                                   │
│ ❱ 119 │   │   │   │   │   scene = SceneClass()                               │
│   120 │   │   │   │   │   scene.render()                                     │
│   121 │   │   │   except Exception:                                          │
│   122 │   │   │   │   error_console.print_exception()                        │
│                                                                              │
│ /opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/scene/scene │
│ .py:147 in __init__                                                          │
│                                                                              │
│    144 │   │   │   )                                                         │
│    145 │   │   else:                                                         │
│    146 │   │   │   self.renderer = renderer                                  │
│ ❱  147 │   │   self.renderer.init_scene(self)                                │
│    148 │   │                                                                 │
│    149 │   │   self.mobjects = []                                            │
│    150 │   │   # TODO, remove need for foreground mobjects                   │
│                                                                              │
│ /opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/renderer/ca │
│ iro_renderer.py:54 in init_scene                                             │
│                                                                              │
│    51 │   │   self.static_image = None                                       │
│    52 │                                                                      │
│    53 │   def init_scene(self, scene):                                       │
│ ❱  54 │   │   self.file_writer: Any = self._file_writer_class(               │
│    55 │   │   │   self,                                                      │
│    56 │   │   │   scene.__class__.__name__,                                  │
│    57 │   │   )                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│ /opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/manim/scene/scene │
│ _file_writer.py:88 in __init__                                               │
│                                                                              │
│    85 │   │   )                                                              │
│    86 │   │   # fail fast if ffmpeg is not found                             │
│    87 │   │   if not ensure_executable(Path(config.ffmpeg_executable)):      │
│ ❱  88 │   │   │   raise RuntimeError(                                        │
│    89 │   │   │   │   "Manim could not find ffmpeg, which is required for ge │
│    90 │   │   │   │   "For installing ffmpeg please consult https://docs.man │
│    91 │   │   │   │   "Make sure to either add ffmpeg to the PATH environmen │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
RuntimeError: Manim could not find ffmpeg, which is required for generating 
video output.
For installing ffmpeg please consult 
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation.html
Make sure to either add ffmpeg to the PATH environment variable
or set path to the ffmpeg executable under the ffmpeg header in Manim's 
configuration.
[28348] Execution returned code=1 in 1.503 seconds returned signal null 

(manim-env) /Users/rizkylubis/Documents/Coding Projects/>

However when I use my mac's terminal app, I can see that ffmpeg is already installed in my environment:
(manim-env) Rizkys-Macbook-Air:~ rizkylubis$ ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg version 7.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with clang version 16.0.6
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/anaconda3/envs/manim-env --cc=arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang --cxx=arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ --nm=arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-nm --ar=arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-ar --disable-doc --disable-openssl --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libdav1d --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm64 --target-os=darwin --cross-prefix=arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0- --host-cc=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1723846258894/_build_env/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --enable-neon --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-pthreads --enable-libopenvino --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libaom --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libxml2 --enable-pic --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --enable-libopus --pkg-config=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1723846258894/_build_env/bin/pkg-config
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
Unrecognized option '-version'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
(manim-env) Rizkys-Macbook-Air:~ rizkylubis$ 

Note: I am practically very new to coding. The only coding I've done is from the necessary coding projects I need to do for my PDE and quantum classes.
